# Invisible links in mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

Since a couple of days ago I have this problem when browsing the music.SE on my mobile phone (Samsung/android stock browser), and there using the mobile version of the site:
Links in questions and answers that I have clicked earlier are "invisible", i.e. they have the same color (black) as regular non-link text, and there are no other indicators that the link texts are actually links.
Is this a newly introduced "bug"? Or is there something wrong with me? :-)
I am fairly certain that the links used to be red both before and after clicking, only in differently shades. (Clicked links used to be dark red.)

Remarks:

- I have lately not had or done any updates to my phone or the browser.
- I have checked the mobile version with Internet Explorer 8 and can see that the text of previously clicked links there also turn out
  black, however in IE8 they become underlined. It seemes that the
  underline:ing is what's missing in my mobile browser, although I
  prefered them being colored dark red.
- Using the full site on my
  mobile phone the links show as different shades of blue - no problem,
  except I prefer the mobile site on my mybile phone.

**Update:**
Today (feb 24) the clicked links are back to "normal" red again! Afaik I haven't done or changed anything special on my phone that I could imagine would have an impact on this. Haven't checked mobile on IE yet.

Comment: Which version of Android do you have?  Does this happen on other SE sites?

Comment: @MatthewRead: My phone is running Android ICS 4.0.4. However it's due for an update to Jellybean since a couple of days, but I've postponed that for some reasons. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: No, 4.0 should be a supported browser.